# Diffeomorphisms of $\mathbf R^n$

Tags: gr.group-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-topology, transformation-groups

Let $G={\rm Diff}_0^c(\mathbf R^n)$, $n\geq 1$, be the group of compactly supported diffeomorphisms isotopic to the identity through compactly supported isotopies.

**Question:** Is there an example to two nontrivial diffeomorphisms $f,g\in G$ such that $f$ cannot be expressed as a product of up to two conjugates (in $G$) of $g^{\pm 1} $?

**Background:** It follows from the work of Burago-Ivanov-Polterovich and Tsuboi that given two nontrivial diffeomorphisms as above, one can be expressed as a product of up to six conjugates of the other. I am asking for an example where one needs at least three (two is easy).

Comment: compactly isotopic means that the isotopy is the identity outside a compact subset? (so $f$ and $g$ should be equal outside a compact subset?)

Comment: Yes, both of them are compactly supported (=equal to the identity outside a compact subset).

Comment: In the edited post you still don't say that $f$ and $g$ are compactly supported. (Also, in 2, by conjugate, do you mean conjugate by a compactly supported diffeomorphism?) And also "nontrivial" means "not equal to the identity"?

Comment: @YCor Thanks. I hope it is clearer now.